# How to implement Rating in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop a rating system similar to Itunes in an iPhone application.

Can anyone guide me on how to implement it?

Is there any SDK or API available?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/s7ratingview/downloads/detail?name=s7ratingview-basic-release.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement rating by using [static libraty](https://github.com/nesterow/TouchCustoms/wiki/). Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

If i correctly understand your question for  making a Custom UIView: A 5 Star Rating View have a **[look here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view)**....and also you can use the the Appirater class get it from here **[Appirater code](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)** also for more help see this amazing **[blog](http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/tag/appirater/)**

Good Luck!

Comment: The 5 Star Rating View works great.  I just tried it out last evening and it was simple.